# How can I handle multiple lines of output when running external processes with Shelly?

Tags: haskell, shelly

I'm looking for a function of type `Text -> [Text]`, essentially that would split text based by newlines. However I can't just split on `\n` as this could be escaped for example as in `\\n`, I'm not sure what other complications exist.

**Main.hs**

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text.IO
import Shelly

example :: Sh Text
example = run "./example.sh" []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  v <- shelly example
  Data.Text.IO.putStrLn v
```

**example.sh**

```
echo "test1\\n"
echo "test2"
echo "test3"
```

Output of `./example.sh`:

```
test1\n
test2
test3
```

So this is output of 3 lines.

Does Shelly support some functionality to handle the above? Or maybe some other Haskell library to parse the output? I guess it would look something like `putStrLn` but instead of being output to `IO ()` it would be output to `[Text]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html#v:lines

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  v <- shelly example
  print $ Data.Text.lines v
```